# jQuery Animate not working with values passed as parameters inside function

Tags: jquery, animation, parameters

I am having problems getting jQuery's `animate` function to work with *dynamic values*.
I have created a function that will accept a DOM element along with some options for animating it.

**Here is my HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <h2> CSS Transform Translate </h2>
    <p> For Moving the Heading </p>
</div>
```

**Here is my CSS:**

```
body {
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    color: #333333;
    padding: 40px 0;
}
h2 { border: 1px solid lightblue; }
p { border: 1px solid lightgreen; }
```

**Here is my JavaScript:**

```
var a = function(element, options) {

    if( ! element ) return false;

    options = options || {};

    var property = options.property || 'transform',
        value    = options.value    || 'translateY(-100px)',
        timing   = options.timing   || 3000;

    return $(element).animate({

        property : value

    }, timing);

};

a('h2');
```

When calling my function `a`, along with the DOM Element on its own, it doesn't trigger the animation. The function `a` runs, returning the DOM element to the console but nothing happens on the page and the css applied through animation doesn't show up in the web inspector either.

When passing every option, the same happens.

Here is the fiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/loxyboi/ahuk5c1r/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can animate `transform` using the `animate` function. You use CSS transitions though, and add them using jQuery. For example:

```
$('h2').css({
    'transform': 'translateY(-100px)',
    'transition': 'transform 3s ease-in'
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/StathisG/pa3f61bc/

---

Apart from the above, the problem with your function is that you cannot pass variables into the animate function this way.

So, instead of this:

```
return $(element).animate({
    property : value
}, timing);
```

You can do the following:

```
var animation_options = {}
animation_options[property] = value;
return $(element).animate(animation_options, timing);
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/StathisG/0bq56kaz/

Also, I removed the `setTimeout` that you had there, since it doesn't seem to make sense (at least in this example).

Comment: Thanks @StathisG, that's clearly one problem. But unfortunately, I still can't get the `animate` function to work within my function `a`, even when executing an animation on a css property that is actually possible, such as `font-size`. Here is the updated version of the fiddle, with `font-size` in place of `transform`: http://jsfiddle.net/loxyboi/g5arrpeh/

Comment: Thanks @StathisG, that works great. I didn't realise I couldn't pass variables into jQuery's animate like that.